# Drupal: APi coding and fields in a fieldset

Tags: drupal

I am coding my own Drupal module and working with the form api to create the fields that make up the form on a page. I have fields defined like: $form['username'].

Now i would like to have a fieldset for the fields, which results in the following definition: $form["settings"]["username"].

Question: which other code does this affect? for example i have code like $form_state['values']['username'], does this need to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to delve into those levels.  Therefore, in order to access `$form['settings']['username']`, use `$form_state['values']['settings']['username']`.

Comment: This turned out to be false and I had to spent hours debugging my code because of your suggestion. Thanks a lot, dude.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `$form_state['values']['username']` would be the same, unless you set `'#tree' => true` in the fieldset, then you would use `$form_state['values']['settings']['username']`.